# Do i really need a new Solr collection?

Tags: java, solr, lucene, nosql, solrcloud

I'm using Apache Solr to index data from different sources. Each source produces documents that are slightly different from the other. Not completely different... just *slightly*.

For instance, let's say that i have **10 sources**. The documents produced from all the source **share 3 fields**. Each of the 10 sources however introduces **5 specific fields** that are present only in documents from that source.

Should I:

1. Rely on 1 solr collection with **very sparse data**, having a schema with 80 fields where i know that only 8 fields could be used in each document?
2. Rely on 10 solr collections with **very dense data**, having 10 schemas with 8 fields each, always used?

Of course solution 2 is harder to maintain and doesn't allow me to query on data from all sources by one of the shared fields. On the other side I'm afraid that solution 1 could have worse performances (on select and also on insert) and waste more storage space.

What could be the best solution? We are going to store about 1 billion documents. I have not been able to find any resource helping me in this decision.

Comment: Option 2 is not really a solution unless you have specific requirements to separate them out completely. I do not know why you would consider option 1 to waste storage space, because it doesn't. Introduce a "source" field to track the source of each records in your 1 collection approach and do a proper scaling with sharding and replica. You would be fine.

Comment: Thank you @WinnieDaPooh So in general there is no overhead in inserting documents with many empty fields? I should use more than one collection only if strictly needed?

Comment: You can use different collection if you don't have a use case that goes across different source. And, No, there should be no overhead with many empty fields.